# Determining the angles of a triangle given the ratio between its edges

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

Given that a triangle has edges of ratio 2 : 3 : 4, the task is to determine the three angles, say in degrees. I started by drawing 4 cm segment on the paper, then drew perpendicular segments of lengths 2 and 3 cm going up from the endpoints of the original segment. With a compass I drew arcs from the endpoints of the perpendicular segments, and their intersection allowed me to determine a triangle s.t. its edges meet the 2 : 3 : 4 (cm) ratio requirement. Visually:

[image]

As happy as I am for being able to construct the triangle, I don't quite know how to proceed. I feel that the 2-4 angle (sorry I forgot to label) is 45°, the 3-4 one 30°, leaving 105° for the 2-3 angle. But I need some guidance as to how to approach actually *proving* those (or if those guesses are wrong, how to determine the actual angles). Thanks in advance for any hints/suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let your triangle be $ABC$, with $A$ at the bottom left, $B$ at the bottom right, and $C$ on top.

Drop a perpendicular from $C$ to $AB$, meeting $AB$ at $P$.

Let $AP=x$. Then $BP=4-x$. Let $CP=h$.

By the Pythagorean Theorem on the two smaller triangles, we have
$$x^2+h^2=4 \quad\text{and}\quad (4-x)^2+h^2=9.$$
Expand and subtract. We get $16-8x=5$ and therefore $x=\frac{11}{8}$.

It follows that the cosine of the angle at $A$ is equal to $\frac{11/8}{2}$, that is, $\frac{11}{16}$. Thus (calculator) the angle at $A$ is about $46.57^\circ$.

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful. This was much more accessible at my level.

Comment: p.s. I'm extremely happy how the 45 degree guess, which visually seemed so obviously true, turned out to be off to some degree.

Comment: You are welcome. The Law of Cosines suggested in the answer by Peter Woolfitt is very useful

Comment: The $45^\circ$ estimate was in fact a very good estimate, $1\frac{1}{2}$ degrees is not much.

Comment: Since the problem comes from a section on trigonometry of an elementary algebra book, the first thought was that I can use the trigonometric functions, but I had a hard time figuring out the lengths of what you have as 'h' and 'x' here. I see how easy the latter was, but the former would continue giving me trouble.

Comment: Well, now that we know $AP$, it is easy. By the equation $x^2+h^2=4$, it is $\sqrt{4-(11/8)^2}$, which simplifies to $\frac{3}{8}\sqrt{15}$.  **Added:** You might be interested in the Heron Formula (Wikipedia) for the area of a triangle with given sides.

Comment: Thank you André. Unfortunately your kind effort I'm only able to reward with a point. Thank you very much, I learned. (I'll look at Heron; sounds familiar from school days.)

Comment: You are welcome. Points are not the point of this site. Happy to have helped in the learning.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: try using [law of cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines).

Comment: Thank you. Haven't learned about those yet; I'll read ahead and try to apply to this.